# SQL Table Schema For Sub Product Types

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, database-schema

I have a traditional SQL schema with Supplier ==> Product relationship.

However, I also have a couple of 'super' product types that warrant their own data/tables. I've come up with the following schema - bear in mind that I'm using Entity Framework, so navigation is also important to me.

The only duplication is on the niche product table, where SupplierID has been added to maintain a relationship with NicheSupplier.

NicheSupplier is required because there is some additional information, that only niche suppliers have based on having 1 or more niche products.

If necessary, I can add a relationship directly with Supplier too (good for EF nav).

I've identified athat a couple of triggers will also be necessary to the niche tables to ensure integrity.

I'm no SQL expert - in fact, far from it, so I would appreciate comments and advice as to whether there are better patterns for this type of scenario, or there is anything inheritently bad.

[image: SQL Schema for sub product data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schema is close, but not quite there, you do need the link from `dbo.NicheProduct.SupplierID` to `dbo.NicheSupplier.SupplierID`, but you also need to add the link from dbo.Product to dbo.NicheProduct, to ensure that the combination of supplier and product id in NicheSupplier is a valid combination. To do this you need to add a Unique constraint to dbo.Prodcut on (ProductID, SupplierID), this allows a foreign key on `NicheProduct` ensuring that the combination is valid. This means that triggers are not required to maintain integrity. So your SQL would look something like:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Supplier
(
        ID INT IDENTITY,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Supplier__ID PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.NicheSupplier
(
        SupplierID INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_NicheSupplier__SupplierID PRIMARY KEY (SupplierID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_NicheSupplier__SupplierID FOREIGN KEY (SupplierID) 
        REFERENCES dbo.Supplier (ID)
);
CREATE TABLE dbo.Product 
(
        ID INT IDENTITY,
        SupplierID INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Product__ID PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Product__SupplierID FOREIGN KEY (SupplierID) 
        REFERENCES dbo.Supplier (ID),
    CONSTRAINT UQ_Product__ID_SupplierID UNIQUE (ID, SupplierID)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.NicheProduct
(
        ProductID INT NOT NULL,
        SupplierID INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_NicheProduct__ProductID PRIMARY KEY (ProductID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_NicheProduct__ProductID_SupplierID FOREIGN KEY (ProductID, SupplierID) 
        REFERENCES dbo.Product (ID, SupplierID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_NicheProduct__SupplierID FOREIGN KEY (SupplierID) 
        REFERENCES dbo.NicheSupplier (SupplierID)
);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the advice Gareth - took me a while just to understand your answer, so I would never have thought of it - cheers!